# Round a float value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding

I have a float values like `31.4032, 31.5266, etc...`. I need this values to be rounded to the nearest 0.25 like `31.00, 31.25, 31.50, 31.75, 32.00, 32.25, 32.50, etc...`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: checkout this blog.. http://pullmonkey.com/2008/01/31/rounding-to-the-nearest-number-in-ruby/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, multiply your number by 4, then round that and divide by 4.

```
>> x = 31.4032
>> (x * 4).round / 4.0
=> 31.5
```